# How to remove DBProject from my solution's sequence of build

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, debugging

Any time I try to debug my web project by pressing F5, the DBProj also get rebuilt and deployed. The deploying aspect takes time and I want to avoid this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on visual studio, find the combobox with "Debug, Release, Configuration Manager"

select "Configuration Manager", a window will popup, uncheck the projects you dont want to build and voila.

[image]

Comment: my pleasure, don't forget to check the question as answered, good luck